# Picking phase terms out of an exponential

Tags: list-manipulation, simplifying-expressions, replacement

I need to pick out certain terms from a sum of exponentials. For example, in the sum below:

$a + b e^{i\,\Delta\,t} + c e^{ i( (\Delta + \Omega) t + \varphi_{0})} + \Delta e^{i\,\delta\,t + \varphi_{1}}$

I want to pick out

$a + d e^{i\,\delta\,t + \varphi_{1}}$

where those terms are chosen because I know in advance that $\Delta$ and $\Omega$ are large, and I want to ignore any "fast oscillating terms" like $e^{i\,\Delta\,t}$.

I have a large sum of exponential terms being returned, which will change, so this can't be done by hand. I can't just set $t\rightarrow0$ and/or $\Delta\rightarrow 0$ because there are terms with prefactors that will remain if the exponential is set to 1 ($\Delta$ or $c$ in the example above).

Any thoughts? I went down a path with something like

```
expr = a + b E^(I Δ t) + c E^(i (Δ + Ω) t + φ0) + Δ E^(I δ t + φ1)
expr = expr /. Exp[x_]:> someFunc[x]
```

but I couldn't figure out an appropriate someFunc[x]. Any thoughts?

Thanks so much in advance!!

Comment: Could you provide some more examples or elaborate on the selection criteria?  It is not clear to me from this one example and your description what a general solution would need to accomplish.

Comment: @Jaffe42 I encourage you to [edit] you question as soon as possible, because as it stands it risks been put [on-hold](https://goo.gl/jXYaiD), as it's not clear what you need. To avoid or revert the Hold you can [edit] your question and [improve it](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3) and make it specific, well-structured with more examples and provide a less ambiguous explanation of the requirements. Please don't be discouraged by that cleaning-up policy. Your questions are and will be most welcomed. Learn about [good questions here](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3).

Comment: Note that $c\,e^{i \phi_0}$ is not a term but a factor of the 3rd term of the original expression. Not sure it makes sense to set the oscillatory factor to one when in the 2nd term it’s set to zero.

Comment: @MichaelE2, you're totally right I gave a mistaken example (not helping the clarity). I'll edit the question.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, Sorry for being unclear. I have some variables that I know are large (here, Δ and Ω). I want to ignore terms that rapidly accumulate phase, such as $e^{i\,\Delta\,t}$. MichaelE2 pointed out an error I made that makes the problem much easier, and I've edited the question accordingly. Seems like an answer now could be `someFunc[x_] := If[FreeQ[x, Δ], If[FreeQ[x, Ω], Exp[x], 0], 0]`. I'd still be curious to know if there's a better way though! Sorry again for the confusion, feel free to delete this question if it's confusing or not worth keeping up. Thanks again everyone!!

Answer (score 0):

Your question unclear and confusing! However, maybe you can try something like this:

```
With[{\[CapitalDelta] = 0, \[CapitalDelta]t = 0}, 
 a + \[CapitalDelta] E^(I \[CapitalDelta] t) + 
  c E^(i (\[CapitalDelta] + \[CapitalOmega]) t + \[CurlyPhi]0) + 
  d E^(I \[Delta] t)]
```